# A Symmetric Matrix Question (Diagonalization)

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $C$ is a symmetric matrix, and we have $V$ being another matrix such that $V^TCV$ happens to be equal to a diagonal matrix $D$.

Does this mean $D$ must be "the" diagonal matrix with diagonal entries being the eigenvalues of $C$, and $V$ must be the matrix consisting of the eigenvectors of $C$?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: No and no. And even if you assume $V$ to be orthogonal, then the word "the" implies a uniqueness that does not hold.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Can we at least conclude that V is a matrix consisting of the eigenvectors? I know orthogonal diagonalization is not unique, but it's unique up to a permutation of columns, which are eigenvectors, right?

Comment: Yes, if $V$ is orthogonal. But not "of the eigenvectors" but "of eigenvectors".

Comment: @darijgrinberg Right now, we don't know anything about V. And the only thing we know is that D is some diagonal matrix. And they happen to make $V^TCV = D$ hold. What can we say about V and D, though? I hope I can conclude that the columns of V are eigenvectors of C, and diagonal entries of D are eigenvalues of C. Is this possible?

Comment: Even then, the answer is no... The answer only becomes yes if $V$ is assumed to be orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, unless $V$ is orthogonal. In that case the answer is yes, but not exactly as you stated: $D$ must have the eigenvalues of $C$ on the diagonal, and the columns of $V$ are eigenvectors (which are not unique, and even less so when the eigenvalues have higher multiplicity).

For example 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 5 & -2 \\-2 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 10 \\ 10& 29 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 5 & -2 \\-2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$
is an obvious counterexample.

The counterexample is constructed from
$$\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 10 \\ 10& 29 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 1& 2 \\ 2& 5\end{bmatrix}^2 \\
\begin{bmatrix} 5 & -2 \\-2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1& 2 \\ 2& 5\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

**P.S.**  If $V$ is assumed orthogonal, meaning $V^{-1}=V^T$, then the answer becomes yes. In that case, your equation can be written as 
$$CV=VD$$
Then, if $v_1,.., v_n$ are the columns of $V$, and $d_1,.., d_n$ the diagonal entries of $D$, the $j^{th}$ column of $CV$ is $Cv_j$ while the $j^{th}$ column of $VD$ is $v_jd_j$. Therefore, by the above you have 
$$Cv_j=d_jv_j$$